# How to get Apache Server to display test page

Tags: apache, centos

I am trying to set up an Apache Server on a CentOS 5.9 machine but I am not seeing the Apache test page when I get visit my machines IP Address on port 80 in my browser. Apache/httpd comes prepackaged with CentOS and I have already ensured the httpd service is running and `NameVirtualHost *:80` has been uncommented in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, Everything else is httpd.conf is set to the defaults. There are no errors in the httpd log and the service restarts fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: is your firewall open?  does it work when you go to `localhost`?

Comment: Are you trying to access with another machine? Is the port 80 opened on the firewall?

Comment: @Russell Uhl: I'll check the firewall, what do you mean when I go to localhost? How can I test the Apache Server locally? All I have been doing is trying to load the page from a remote browser.

Comment: on the same machine as the server, go to the address bar where you would normally enter the url, and just type `localhost`.  IF you see the "it works" page then you know you have successfully configured the server and it is running.  IF not, something is wrong with your configuration/server is not running.

Comment: @Russell Uhl The server does not have a gui. It is all command line. Is there a command I can run to check Apache?

Comment: You can try with `curl localhost` if the server is working you'll see the HTML code of the default page, thus you'll know the problem is the firewall that block port 80.

Comment: You could also try `telnet localhost 80` to see if the port is even open.  Remember, these commands are done on the SERVER, not on the client.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It was indeed the firewall. That `curl` command was very useful as well.

Comment: I'll summarise it all in an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if apache is serving the default page point your browser to `http://localhost`. If you haven't a GUI you can access your server with `curl localhost` which will print on your stdout the HTML code of your default page.

If you're trying to access to your server from a remote machine you should check if there's a running firewall and if the port 80 is opened `iptables -vnL`. If not, open it with `iptables -A INPUT -p TCP -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I updated iptables with above mentioned command. Now i am unable to connect to the server itself using Putty. Getting error - connect to host hostname port 22: Connection refused @Vilelm